# How to fetch Shopify store orders using Shopify's API

Tags: r, shopify, httr

I'm struggling to import the orders for a Shopify development store using the [httr](https://github.com/r-lib/httr) package in R.  Here's what I've tried.

1. I've created a [development store](https://help.shopify.com/partners/dashboard/development-stores) and made some fake orders.
2. Within my development store, I added a private app and generated my API key and Password
3. Following [this article](https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication/private-authentication), I tried implementing the following request

Code

```
apikey <- "foo"
pass <- "bar"

shop <- GET(
  url = "my-test-store.myshopify.com/orders.json", 
  authenticate(user = apikey, password = pass)
)
```

But this gives a 401 status code.  However, this works but returns xml instead of json

```
shop <- GET(
  url = "my-test-store.myshopify.com/orders", 
  authenticate(user = apikey, password = pass)
)
```

How can I retrieve the results as JSON instead of XML?

Note that I can also fetch the orders using the R package [shopifyr](https://github.com/charliebone/shopifyr) but would rather not use that package as it is no longer maintained.

Comment: just asking: should it be admin/orders.json?
 https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order

Comment: Shoot, that was a copy-paste error.  However, I figured out what I was doing wrong.  About to post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update 2019-05-13

I created an R package called [shopr](https://github.com/ben519/shopr) for querying data via the Shopify API. Fetching orders looks like this

```
library(shopr)

shopr_get_orders(
  shopURL = "https://my-test-store.myshopify.com", 
  APIKey = "abc123", 
  APIPassword = "def456"
)
```

## Old Answer

Figured it out.

```
orders <- GET(
  url = "https://my-test-store.myshopify.com/admin/orders",
  add_headers(Accept = "application/json"),
  authenticate(user = apikey, password = pass)
)
orders
```

The trick was to explicitly put "https://..." in the url otherwise httr was prepending "http://" to the url, causing my 401 problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Try this:

```r
library(httr)

apikey <- "foo"
pass <- "bar"

orders <- GET(
  url = "https://yourshop.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json", 
  authenticate(user = apikey, password = pass)
)

content(orders)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, but I figured out the solution.  Will post my answer shortly.